# How to order deployment of EJBs and JMS queue config in JBoss 5?

Tags: jboss, jms, ejb, ear, jboss-messaging

I'm using JBoss [EAP] 5.0.0.GA and I have an EAR which contains an EJB jar that contains some MDBs which depend on the existence of the JMS queues that they use. When I configured the queues in `.../server/all/deploy/messaging/myqueues-service.xml` there was no problem.

However, I wanted to configure the queues in the EAR file to avoid having to make changes to the JBoss config directly. No problem, I put my `myqueues-service.xml` file into the root of the EAR and added the reference to my `jboss-app.xml` as follows:

```
<jboss-app>
    <module-order>strict</module-order>
    <loader-repository>
        seam.jboss.org:loader=my-ear.ear
    </loader-repository>
    <module>
        <service>myqueues-service.xml</service>
    </module>
</jboss-app>
```

However, when I do that, JBoss loads the EJB jar (contained in my-ear.ear) first and then configures the JMS Queues afterwards. This results in errors when the MDB are loaded:

```
12:16:02,714 WARN  [JmsActivation] Failure in jms activation org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivationSpec@13a59e .....
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MyQueue not bound
```

It's not a huge problem, as later on the MDBs successfully reconnect to JMS:

```
12:16:12,698 INFO  [JmsActivation] Attempting to reconnect org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivationSpec@f91ad5
12:16:12,823 INFO  [JmsActivation] Reconnected with messaging provider.
```

But I'd really like to avoid having any errors, and in order to do that I need a way to force JBoss to configure the JMS queues first, before loading the EJB jar. Is there any way to do this? For reference, here's the `application.xml` for the EAR:

```
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:application="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" version="5">
  <display-name>my-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>my-ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>my.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>myroot</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, [jaikiran pai](http://community.jboss.org/message/579299#579299) on the community.jboss.org forums helped me out. The solution is to add the JMS Queue as a dependency on the MDB. In my case I used the @Depends annotation:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue/MyQueue") })
@Depends("jboss.messaging.destination:service=Queue,name=MyQueue")
public class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {
    ...
}
```

You could do the same using jboss.xml if you aren't using annotations.

Comment: Just a bit more useful into: if you don't want to put the myqueues-service.xml file in the .../server/all/deploy/messaging/ folder, and don't want to include it in the EAR either, then you can put it in .../server/all/deploy/ (using the "Make Deployable" in Eclipse, or just copying it there). That removes the need for declaring explicit dependencies in the MDB, whilst at the same time not altering the default JBoss server config.